# How to style textbox using CSS in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css

I want to add style in ASP.NET textbox control. I couldn't find textbox element in elements list. I can put style in all input controls using the below code in CSS.

```
input
{
backgroud-color:black;
}
```

But this changes the background color of all input controls like buttons, radiobox, etc.

I want to do it exclusively with textbox, I don't want to do it with CSS class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do it:

```
input[type=text]
```

Though it might not work in all browsers (e.g. IE). The only way to ensure that would be to add a class or put it inside a span element.

Comment: also can use [type=text]

Answer (score 9):

It would be easier to put css class on those textboxes (input type="text")

```
<style>
   .textbox { /*some style here */ }
</style>

<input type="text" class="textbox" /> or
<asp:TextBox id="someid" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" />
```

Answer (score 3):

A 100% cross browser, that works in IE6, is to make use of [asp.net themes and skins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx). Create a [skin file](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040105.htm) in the app_themes directory and add the following line:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="textbox" />
```

This will then apply the CSS class "textbox" to *every* textbox in your site, assuming you have corresponding CSS and theme references.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for but you can put `CssClass="myTextBoxStyle"` in the ASP.NET server-side tag and then define a class called `.myTextBoxStyle` in your stylesheet.  It will then only affect textboxes where you've added `CssClass="myTextBoxStyle"`

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type=text]
```

but won't work in IE.

Use a class name instead and apply that class to your text elements.